# Reference for action-angle coordinates

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry, classical-mechanics, perturbation-theory

Does anyone know a good reference to start studying Action-Angle coordinates?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

V. I. Arnold, **Mathematical Methods for Classical Mechanics**, p. 280.

L. D. Landau and E. M. Lifshitz, **Mechanics**, p. 157.